Fourier transform of a positive function
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ be a positive function i.e. $f(x) > 0$. Then, what can be said about it's Fourier transform ( or it's FFT )? We can even restrict $f$ to a positive, even, convex function. I've found this which seems to be something like what I want and this which I don't quite understand if it is going to be useful for me.
Basically, I'm interested in Fourier Neural Operators (FNOs) and I'd like to learn a positive function (the kernel) by learning it's Fourier transform (FFT, really) and then taking the inverse transform. Hence, I'm seeking what conditions I need to impose on the FFT of the function in order for the function to be positive.

Positive definite function doesn't mean $f(x)>0$. Instead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function
For an introduction see  http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/590/notes/Notes590_Ch2Part2Print.pdf

Thanks, removed the word "definite". BTW, the second definition on Wikipedia is quite close to my usage of positive definite.

I guess this is not a good question - any bounded function can be made positive by adding a constant.

At least one of the links you provided refers to the first definition. And my guess is that it is indeed Bochner's theorem that you are looking for. Have a look at page 16 of Fasshauer's lecture notes that I linked and see whether this is what you want. Since you mentioned FFT: in the finite-dimendional setting you "can" think of positive definite functions as circulant positive definite matrices. Circulant matrices are diagonalized by the FFT, and if their diagonal is positive then the matrix is positive definite. Note that there is some mismatch in the usage of positive definite in the lit.

You might be correct. I think what I'm really looking for is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel.  Bochner seems to give a representation of a positive definite function, and if I want to think about it's Fourier transform, I should take it's Fourier transform and see what I get.

A positive definite function induces a translation invariant positive definite kernel (you can write its application through a convolution). A general positive definite kernel, however, does not have to be diagonalized by Fourier transform. It's probably simpler to consider the finite-dimensionsl setting: a circulant matrix represents a circulant convolution and is diagonalized by the DFT. An arbitrary real symmetric matrix has an orthonormal eigendecomposition, and is positive definite if the eigenvalues are. Mercer's series expansion is something like that.

The eigenvectors of an arbitrary symmetric matrix are not given by the DFT in general though. You should probably edit your answer to clarify what it is that you want. You mention positive definite function there, but then speak of a discrete transform (the DFT/FFT), and then you mention positive definite kernels here. A symmetric matrix would be positive definite if its eigenvalues are all positive, in the special case of a circulant matrix you can use DFT/FFT and just learn positive (or non-negative) eigenvalues.
